# ZendFramework integration with other frameworks

Tags: php, javascript, css, zend-framework, frameworks

I want to make this question a guide for those interested in [ZendFramework](http://framework.zend.com/) integration with other libraries/frameworks. Searching over StackOverflow doesn't give a broad view on the subject.

The question is: which libraries/frameworks do you use in your current ZF-based project? what are the best practices for ZF-based project architecture?

I don't mean any components that are *already* a part of ZF. Please give a description of **aditional** frameworks you have integrated (like [RuckUsing](http://code.google.com/p/ruckusing/), [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)). It also applies to any GUI frameworks (perhaps you use a CSS framework), as well as JS frameworks (not just [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), but rather some advanced structures).

The main requirement: it has to be a ZendFramework project.

Additional bonus will be given to answers that describe performance optimization.

**UPDATE**

Every answer as informative as @BryanM's will be considered for additional bounty award.

Comment: +1 for link to RuckUsing- never heard of it

Comment: Well basically it boils down to (if its an PHP Application) if it you can implement the bootstrap process and if the autoloader's can work alongside each other, there a lot tutorials on zend framework and doctrine integration, unfortunately I haven't found anyone that applies to the current Doctrine Beta. The matter with JS and CSS can be completely encapsulated from the Use of the PHP Application in that regard (imho) - in any case +1 for raising an interesting Point!

Comment: @Hannes As I stated in the question, it's not really HOW to integrate different frameworks, but rather WHAT frameworks to choose for the application. Bootstrapping and writing custom plugins is fine, as long as it's reusable, and I fully take this advantage. But having spaghetti-like architecture sucks, so I would like to see good examples of real-world applications with mature features (CI, DB Migrations etc).

Answer (score 9):

I use Doctrine 2 in my Zend Framework projects. It's easy to use and fits in seamlessly. The basic steps to integrate it are:

- Write a resource plugin that will initialize a Doctrine 2 EntityManager using configurations options in `application.ini`. An example of one can be found in Benjamin Eberlei's [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions).
- Rather than rely on a global registry (`Zend_Registry`) to store the EntityManager reference, I rely on a simple depedency injection solution as [described here](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/235-A-Simple-Resource-Injector-for-ZF-Action-Controllers.html) to provde the instance to my controllers.
- I rely on Doctrine's Event system to create re-usable 'behavior' classes to do things like update timestamps or validate data.
- I keep all my Entities and business objects in my application's 'models' folder (under it's own namespace), and everything else in in my `library` folder. I heavily use PHP 5.3 namespaces to keep things organized.
- I use Doctrine's new-ish Migrations library to handle updates to the database via the command line.
- I also highly recommend creating a detailed build process in [Phing](http://phing.info/trac/) in order to handle library dependencies, automated unit testing and running migrations that can be integrated into source control or a CI Server. Also good for compiling Javascript or CSS if you're using one of those frameworks.

These practices aren't just good for Doctrine, they'll be handy anytime you're trying to built a site's architecture. I think that Zend's biggest assets in extensibility are Resource plugins and ActionHelpers / Controller Plugins.

Comment: +1 do you use cron jobs? js/css frameworks? any performance optimization?

Comment: Cron jobs are fine for things that need cron. Not specific to ZF apps. Doctrine 2 relies on storing pre-compiled metadata in a cache, and auto-generates Proxy class files for lazy loading. Essentially, don't do anything at run-time that can be done ahead-of-runtime.

Comment: bounty is given to you as you've given the most informative answer.

Answer (score 3):

Also remember [HtmlPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) for HTML sanitization, typically parsing user-provided markup, based upon a whitelist of allowable tags, and producing standards-compliant output markup.

It can be used as a first line of defense against XSS attacks. Note that `Zend_Filter_StripTags` is [*not* sufficient](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2010/08/html-sanitisation-the-devils-in-the-details-and-the-vulnerabilities/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

- ZendX_JQuery (a tutorial is available on [zendcast.com](http://www.zendcasts.com/working-with-zendx_jquery/2010/07/)).
- Although, it's a ruby application, we use [webistrano](https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/wiki/) to deploy php projects.
- If your web application has to do full-text search on a large scale, i would use sphinx in combination with zend ([sorgalla.com](http://sorgalla.com/2010/01/18/sphinx-und-sphinxse-ins-zend-framework-integrieren/)).
- If you want to use those new NoSQL-Databases like MongoDB, you could use [morph](http://code.google.com/p/mongodb-morph/wiki/BasicUsage) as high level php-library. I just copied the files to 'library' and told the autoloader to load the files: autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Morph_".
- [ZF_Debug](http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/) is a nice debugging toolbar for development.